# CSS: How to create a drop menu using relative position and multiple items

Tags: css

I am trying to create a drop-down menu for when the user hovers an item in another menu.

My current HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="menu-main-items">Item1</li>
        <ul id="submenu">
            <li>Sub-item1</li>
            <li>Sub-item2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-main-items">Item2</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.menu-main-items{display:inline;}

#submenu{display:none;}

li:hover #submenu{ //display the submenu below the parent main item }
```

To align the sub-menu with the parent item, I was thinking using `position:relative;` on `#submenu` and adding a certain offset, but that causes flickering, as the sub-menu is being displayed before item 2, rearranging the menu. As of now I have searched around and could only find explanation with one item in the main menu which doesn't cause the problem.

Is there another way to approach this?

Comment: `position: absolute`?

Comment: @YaakovAinspan I tried but I have to set an horizontal offset as well which doesn't appear aligned with changing resolution.

Comment: Just realized: in your code, the `ul` element is not a child of the `li` element. Is that deliberate?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be based on the context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make the `li` elements `inline-block` and change the positioning to `absolute`. The flickering is because the element is being shown and pushing the content out of the way as it is inserted into the flow. `position: absolute` removes it from the flow, getting rid of the flicker.

If you want to move the submenu relative to the parent, add `position: relative` to the parent and use `top` and `left` (`bottom` and `right` aren't really useful) to move it.

For more information, see [this CSS-Tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/solved-with-css-dropdown-menus/).

```css
.menu-main-items{
  display:inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

#submenu{
  display:none;
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
}

li:hover #submenu{ 
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="menu-main-items">Item1
        <ul id="submenu">
            <li>Sub-item1</li>
            <li>Sub-item2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-main-items">Item2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! But the submenu is too much to the right. padding-left manages to move it to the right but padding-right doesn't do anything.

Comment: Absolute items should be moved using, left right top and bottom. Padding and margins wont do the trick

Comment: @JurjenFolkertsma Using left breaks the relation between the position of hte submenu and the related item and positions it in relation to the entire page.

Comment: @Joujoubox only if its parent is not relatively positioned. If the parent has `position: relative`, then `position: absolute` is relative to the parent, not the page.

Answer (score -1):

Li : position: relative;

Ul.submenu : position: absolute;

You can position the submenu relative to the li using:
Top, bottom, left, right.

Example

```
Li {position: relative}
Ul {position: absolute;top:25px;left:0;}
```

You can hide and show on hover

```
Ul {display: none;}
Li.mainmenu-items:hover > ul {display: block;}
```

The > in the css rule means it only targets the first element of the specified child under it. So this is the first level of ul,s inside of the current item hovered